# Wordpress ob_start white screen

Tags: php, wordpress

I have problem call class in class. Main class code:

```
class Project_one {

protected $minify;

function __construct() {
    $this->minify = new Minify();
    add_action('get_header', array($this->minify, 'loader'));
}}
```

Minify class is call in _construct function. Minify class code:

```
class Minify{

public function loader() { 
    ob_start(array($this, 'html'));        
}

private function html($html) {}}
```

Problem: when i try load loader() function i get blank screen. I think html() function don't get HTML code from ob_start function. How i can fix it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable PHP errors in order to see errors instead of a blank page, do it in either `php.ini` or add this to a file:

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Comment: Thanks. I found my bug.

Comment: What was the bug @djjmz?